# i have a function in solidity ,i want return length of new random array generated

Tags: random, blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts, keccak

please can any one help me to get a new length of arandom array generated from this function
What happens now is that the array length is returned to zero

```
 function randomArray(uint[] memory  population ) public view   returns(uint[] memory){
        uint  a = population.length; 
       uint   b = population.length; 
        for(uint i = 0; i< b ; i++){
            uint randNumber =(uint(keccak256      
            (abi.encodePacked(block.timestamp,population[i]))) % a)+1;
            uint interim = population[randNumber - 1];
            population[randNumber-1]= population[a-1];
            population[a-1] = interim;
            a = a-1;
        }
        
        result = population; 
             
        return result;  
        len = result.length;
```

}

Comment: The error message is telling you where to look. A good strategy in these situations can be to take out code until it compiles, and then reintroduce it until it breaks. I'm not familiar with this language, but in `keccak256(abi.encode(uint expandValues[])` — is that `uint` needed? In most languages I know, it would cause a similar error. And it's right around where the error is.

Comment: Before I mention the uint I object to the fact that expandvalues ​​is an undecleared identifier? What do I do in this case?

Comment: I'm not familiar with this language, so I can't help much. I'm also unsure what you're trying to accomplish in that line/function. But basically you need to either declare the variable first, or else just instantiate the object you need (`new uint[]`?) and pass it to the function.

Comment: Good luck! Sorry I couldn't help more :-)

Comment: You should have type declaration `uint` in the function call.

Comment: good declared uint ,but anothor error accur (TypeError: Return argument type bytes32 is not implicitly convertible to expected type (type of first return variable) uint256[] memory.
  --> contracts/paper.sol:11:12:
   |

Comment: Sorry for the long post but I'm very new to this language